# Angular – move focus from input field to list

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, focus

I'm trying to make an autocomplete input field in Angular. I've made both the input field, the call to the restAPI and the list, so now I'm trying to move focus from the input field to the list, so that I can scroll trough the list using the arrow-up/arrow-down keys. I just cant get it to work. I've made a simplyfied fiddle ... any ideas on how to make it?

```
<div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cubanpete/1b41mu1r/4/

Comment: `I've made a simplyfied fiddle`, post this fiddle here too.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle to us?